# tree and datatable mapiing with multiview

Tags: javascript, jquery, webix

am new to webix, and am trying to work around the file manager component, so i have a tree representing file structure like
[tree structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oGKQX.png)

```
Tree function here

  var docTree ={
  view:"tree",
 // editable:true,
  editor:"text",
   select:true,
   css:"doc_tree",
   id:"docTree",
   width:300,
   height:500,
   data:pdf_data,
   drag:true,
   type:"lineTree",
   };

  data-table  function here

  var dataTable ={

  view: "datatable",
  id:"dataTable",
   columns: [
   { id: "Name", header: "...", width: 2}, // 1st col displays item 'IDs'
   { id: "Date" }, // 2nd col displays item 'titles'
   { id: "Type" },  // 3rd col displays item 'values'
   { id: "size" } 
     ]

     };
```

so i want the folder files to be displaying in the data-table per click on the tree like an explorer, i believe it as to do with multi-view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can attach a selection handler to the tree widget and from it call data loading command to fill the grid with the data

```
docTree.attachEvent("onAfterSelect", function(id){
  dataTable.clearAll();
  dataTable.load("/files/"+id);
})
```